# csv to frequency polygon using R or python

Tags: r, csv, frequency

I have a result.csv file to which contains information in the following format :
    date,tweets

```
2015-06-15,tweet
2015-06-15,tweet
2015-06-12,tweet
2015-06-11,tweet
2015-06-11,tweet
2015-06-11,tweet
2015-06-08,tweet
2015-06-08,tweet
```

i want to plot a  frequency polygon with number of entries corresponding to each date as y axis and dates as x axis

i have tried the following code :

```
pf<-read.csv("result.csv")
library(ggplot2)
qplot(datetime, data =pf, geom = "freqpoly")
```

but it shows the following error :
geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

can anyone tell me how to solve this problem. I am totally new to R so any kind of guidance will be of great help to me

Comment: forgot to mention i am able to plot  histogram using the following code          pf<-read.csv("result.csv")
 library(ggplot2)
 qplot(x=datetime,data=pf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to treat datetime as continuous, but it's imported it as a factor (discrete/categorical). Let's convert it to a `Date` object and then things should work:

```
pf$datetime = as.Date(pf$datetime)
qplot(datetime, data =pf, geom = "freqpoly")
```

Comment: thanks sir it worked like a charm . also can you please elaborate a bit more on my silly mistake or just point me to a link so that i dont do these mistakes any more . i mean i just named the column as date time but actually dates were stored in it then why do i need to convert it to a date object again @Gregor

Comment: What you name it doesn't matter. You should get in the habit of looking at the *class* of your columns (`str(pf)` is commonly recommended, if all I want is to know the class I do `sapply(pf, class)`). Dates and times are tricky, they can come in all sorts of different formats and R is cautious about assuming anything. When you want to use something as a date or time you will need to explicitly convert it. I'd recommend reading the vignette for the `lubridate` package.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I assume that the `result.csv` has a header: `datetime, atweet`.  By default, [`read.csv`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) takes the first line of the CSV file as column names. That means you will be able to access the two columns with `pf$datetime` and `pf$atweet`.

If you look at the documentation of `read.csv`, you will find that `stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors()`, which is `FALSE`. That is, the strings from CSV files are kept as [*factors*](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/factor.html).

Now, even if you change the value of `stringsAsFactors`, you still get the same error. That is because `ggplot` does not know how to order the dates, as it does not recognize the strings as such.
To transform the strings into logical dates, you can use `strptime`.

Here is the working example:

```
pf<-read.csv("result.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
library(ggplot2)

qplot(strptime(pf$datetime, "%Y-%m-%d"), data=pf, geom='freqpoly')
```